# How to Run GoogleTestRunner Extension for Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, googletest

I recently upgraded from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2013.  In Visual Studio 2010, I had installed the GTest plugin, and used to right click on either a test name or test case (or the project), and it would run the selected tests.

I just installed the [GoogleTestRunner Extension for Visual Studio 2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9dd47c21-97a6-4369-b326-c562678066f0/view/Discussions/2) and I have no idea how to get it to run all tests or the selected tests.  I followed the instruction from the description about the required project/output name.  But I don't really understand how to run it.  I tried running using the Visual Studio Test Menu -> Run -> All Tests, but it doesn't seem to run properly.  What I see in the Output window:

```
------ Discover test started ------ 
Test run will use DLL(s) built for framework Framework45 and platform X86. Following DLL(s)     will not be part of run:  
test.exe is built for Framework None and Platform X64.  Go to 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=236877&clcid=0x409 for more details on managing these settings. 
GoogleTest: Does c:\src\c++\test\x64\Debug\test.exe match [Tt]est[s]{0,1}.exe: true
```

However this is all that displays. Also, I see that it starts the `test.exe` executable (visible in Task Manager) and it just hangs there doing nothing.

The entire code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << "Starting tests..."; 

    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    RUN_ALL_TESTS();
    getchar();

    return 0;
}

TEST(case1, main_test) {

    ASSERT_EQ(1, 1) << "1 is 1";
}
```

This is using Gtest 1.7.0.

Answer (score 0):

With the extension installed, you should be able to run tests as usual using the 'Test' menu, as well as context-clicking on the test definition itself. Based on the error that you're seeing, it looks like there's a problem with the way that the project is configured, though without additional details about the way that the project is set up (what kind of project this is, what kind of architectures you're targeting, how you're linking against gtest, etc.) it's hard to give any further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove trailing `getchar()` in your application.